# How to create structure destruction like Fortnite in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a fan remake of Fortnite. I already made a construction system and editing, but I don’t know how destruction can be done. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwuvoOXL2vw

**This how it looks in Fortnite - https://youtu.be/EGXYWceVUPU** 
Do you have any ideas how to do this? I tried through checking neighboring cells, but this is not optimized or I did something wrong.

**I will be glad to any advice!**

Comment: you need to post what you have tried and one specific area you are stuck with, your question is far too vague

Answer (score 0):

Using raycasts, you can send out a raycast whenever the player wants to hit something, then if the object has the script that means it can take damage (maybe just use a tag for this), then it will take damage from the object. You could use Brackeys' FPS Shooting tutorial, and adapt that to suit your needs.